# Generate protobuf files for a library target in CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

In the following project structure:

```
root/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ protocol/
│  ├─ msg.proto
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ app/
│  ├─ main.cpp
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

I could generate the protobuf files. However, once the `app` target is added into the project, the configuration step fails, because the protobuf files are not generated anymore.

root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4) 
project(
  root
  VERSION 0.1
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

add_subdirectory(protocol)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

protocol CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(protocol)
target_include_directories(protocol
  PUBLIC
  .
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
set(PROTO_SOURCES msg.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(LIB_SOURCES LIB_HEADERS ${PROTO_SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries(protocol ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
target_sources(protocol
  PUBLIC
  ${LIB_HEADERS}
  PRIVATE
  ${LIB_SOURCES}
)
```

app CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(app)
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC protocol)
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC .)
target_sources(app
  PRIVATE
  main.cpp
)
```

The way I understand it is that somehow I have to tell CMAKE the dependency, but as far as I know `target_link_libraries` should tell exactly that.

Another step I could take is to tell the `app` target that the headers in the `protocol` library are generated at build, so they can be generated before the dependant target compiles. How can it be done?

Many other questions reference similar problems, but none that I found had library dependencies in mind.

---

Update:

After moving `${LIB_HEADERS}` from `PUBLIC` to `PRIVATE`:

```
add_library(protocol)
target_include_directories(protocol
  PUBLIC
  .
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
set(PROTO_SOURCES msg.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(LIB_SOURCES LIB_HEADERS ${PROTO_SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries(protocol ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
target_sources(protocol
  PRIVATE
  ${LIB_HEADERS}
  ${LIB_SOURCES}
)
```

the configure step is successful, the msg.pb.h files are generated into the `protocol` subfloder in `build`; but make fails with the following error:

```
main.cpp:29:10: fatal error: protocol/msg.pb.h: No such file or directory
   29 | #include "protocol/msg.pb.h"
      |
```

So how can the headers be provided from target `protocol` in this setup?

Comment: "However, once the `app` target is added into the project, the configuration step fails, because the protobuf files are not generated anymore." - Do you mean that `LIB_HEADERS` consumed by `app` are not generated? This is true, because `protobuf_generate_cpp` call in `protocol/CMakeLists.txt` is effectively `add_custom_command`, which effect is visibly only inside given `CMakeLists.txt`. Actually, I see no reason in adding `${LIB_HEADERS}` with PUBLIC keyword. Just use PRIVATE keyword.

Comment: Thank you I did, and now the files are generating inside the ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} of the protocol target. Now make fails because compile couldn't find the generated headers. I thought making them into the PUBLIC part of the library would solve this.. How can I make the header files available throuh the library target?

Comment: "Now make fails because compile couldn't find the generated headers." - Do not *describe* the error message. Instead, show it (add to the question post) **as is**.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that, thank  you

Comment: For being able to include the header file via `#include "protocol/msg.pb.h"` you need to specify **include directory**, which contains file at the given **relative path**. "the msg.pb.h files are generated into the `protocol` subfloder in `build`" - So you need to specify `build` as include directory. As it is **top-level build directory** for your project, it can be referred via `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`. (The `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` used in your `protocol/CMakeLists.txt` refers to the **current binary directory**, which is `protocol`.)

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue completely. Would you please type this in as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on help from @Tsyvarev:
After moving `${LIB_HEADERS}` from `PUBLIC` to `PRIVATE`, the protobuf files are now generated.

To make them reachable through the library for the include

```cpp
#include "protocol/msg.pb.h"
```

`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` Needs to be changed into `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` in `target_include_directories`.

In case I the code includes protobuf headers directly:

```cpp
#include "msg.pb.h"
```

`${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` needs to be there.

---

Because:

- `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` represents the submodule binary directoy ( `protocol` project
- `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` represents the project binary directoy ( `protocol` project

Comment: I am not entirely understanding what you did to correct the problem.
Have you made the change in your original problem statement? 
I do not see ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} anywhere.

Comment: My project is compiling (finding all the headers) but the linker is failing.

Comment: Take a look at the part below "Update:".  If the compilation is successful, then your problem is not because of this question, as incorrectly specifying the include directories ( as I did originally ) yields a compile error. 

Based on what you wrote you might have a linkagge problem instead. Try writing a question for it if you don't already found one, and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: I messed with a bunch of things and the problem was resolved. If I can figure out which change corrected the problem I will post it. My guess is that it was due to the Conan profiles which were used.